# overlapping date format in jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to set the datepicker up with a format like this

```
$("#date").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'date_yyyy-mm-dd'
});
```

I want it to output "date_2017-08-22"
but the issue is that it outputs "22ate_20172017-08-22".
Why is it doing that?

Comment: The `dateFormat` accept the following: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Comment: Thanks Dekel that helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The d in date is considered as a day hence the 22 at the beginning, as for the years each 'yy' represents a year if you put 'yyyy' it will print two years as it did in you example, you can use single quotes to put literal text as follows:

```
$("#date").datepicker({
dateFormat: "'date_'yy-mm-dd"
});
```

You can check more documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate), good luck.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much,  I upvoted it but it doesnt show up yet.